# Is there a way to wait for a button to be pressed, but if button is not pressed then program returns?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I am trying to to write a program in which the user in on a screen within Tkinter GUI, and want the system to start from the beginning if a physical button is not pressed.

```py
def start():
    #creating instance
    window = Tk()


def btnclicked(): #ignore this name as its for another button
    def endgame():
        lbltitleend = Label(window, text="Press the button within 5 seconds to quit or the game will restart.", font=("Arial bold", 15), fg="white", bg="black", pady= 15)
        lbltitleend.pack()

        for objectx in objects:
            objectx.destroy()


        def buttonpress():
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
                if (GPIO.input(22) == True):
                    window.destroy()
                    print("Thanks for playing!")
                    del objects[:]
                else:
                    start()


        window.after(500, buttonpress) # Need this so that the program doesnt stall waiting for button to be pressed, and executes everything before the button can be pressed
```

So this just ends up running and so after the 5 seconds of time.sleep it ends up just starting the program again and bringing up a new gui window which I don't mind, but it is not what I want.

What I want is for the program to be waiting for the button to be pressed and if not pressed within 5 seconds then I want it to restart.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that difficult as you already know about `after()` function, there is another function through which we can stop the processing of an `after` thread that is `after_cancel(id)`. "id" is what the after() returns.

**Here is an example of how you can stop before 5 secs complete.**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')

display = Label(root, text='Hello', font=('', 20))
display.pack(pady=40)

def restart():
    display['text'] = 'Restarting...'
    but['state'] = 'disable'            # Once restarted the button gets disabled

def cancel():
    # Cancel the current after with it id
    root.after_cancel(L)
    display['text'] = 'Cancelled'

# Take a reference of after
L = root.after(5000, restart)

but = Button(root, text='Cancel', command = cancel )
but.pack(side='bottom', pady=30)

mainloop()
```

Hope this helped you.